# Is there a way to apply -std=*** in g++ to only one file

Tags: g++

I am in the process of wrapping a large C library with C++ and converting some of the outside layers to C++.

Following the principle of breaking only one thing at a time in a conversion, I am not writing makefiles till later.

I want to do the following:

```
g++ a.c b.c d.c e.c --std=c++11 test.cpp
```

and even

```
g++ a.c b.c d.c  --std=c++11 e.cpp test.cpp
```

a bit later.

Is there a way of specifying that the -std=c++11 only apply to the C++ files?

Comment: There are many quick and dirty ways to do this. But if your project will grow, you should really look into Makefiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to break your compiling process in two different stages:

1) Compile to object files separately with std specifier:

```
g++ -S a.c b.c d.c
g++ -S a.cpp b.cpp d.cpp -std=c++11
```

2) Compile to final executable using all object files generated:

```
g++ -o myelf a.s b.s d.s
```

Comment: It's not a great solution, but it is a solution.

Comment: You can however skip step two and do: g++ -S a.c b.c d.c ; g++ a.s b.s c.s d.cpp -std=c++11